# How can I create a command inside a slide in beamer such that it creates another slide after the current one?

Tags: beamer, macros

So, let me show you a MWE of my problem.

```
\documentclass[serif, aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{euler}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\rascunhoem}[1]{{\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height = \paperheight]{imagens/image.pdf}}\begin{frame}{#1}\end{frame}}}
\newcommand{\questao}[1]{{\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height = \paperheight]{imagens/image.pdf}}\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]#1\end{frame}}\rascunhoem{Rascunho}\rascunhoem{Rascunho}}

\begin{document}

\questao{\lipsum[1-2]\gab{Teste}\lipsum[3-5]}

\end{document}
```

If you want to test it, I'll send a template image in PDF for you to compile, on the link below:

[Link for an example of image.pdf, for the slide's background](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k66emnwbk61wus/image.pdf?dl=0)

So, now here's what I've been trying to do without much success.
As you can see, there's a `\gab{}` command I haven't defined between the `lipsum` paragraphs.

I have lots of blocks of slides with this configuration, in which the first paragraph has the `\gab{}` command (for other purposes) and then the rest of the slide after it.

I'd like to make `\gab{}` to add a slide **after** the two "Rascunho" slides. For example, if I create:

```
\questao{Here's a text example before the command. \gab{This'll be added after the two ``Rascunho'' slides} Here's the text after. 
There's no way I can move the command to the end, I have to leave it here, since I have more than ten thousand blocks like this.}
```

So, I'd like to create a slide after the two "Rascunho" ones with the text ``` This'll be added after the two ``Rascunho'' slides ``` using the `\gab{}` command.

Again, I can't change the command's position along the text, and I can't change the structure I presented. I just want to build the `\gab{}` in such a way it does what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `\gab` to define another macro (here `\@gab`) which is used at the end of your code for `\questao`, e.g.

```
\documentclass[serif, aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\newcommand{\rascunhoem}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}%
   \begin{frame}
   #1
   \end{frame}
   \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\questao}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\@gab{}%
   \def\gab##1{\@bsphack\gdef\@gab{##1}\@esphack}%
   \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}%
   \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
   #1
   \end{frame}
   \rascunhoem{Rascunho}%
   \rascunhoem{Rascunho}%
   \ifx\@gab\@empty
      \def\next{\relax}%
   \else
      \def\next{\begin{frame}\@gab\end{frame}}
   \fi
   \next
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\questao{Here's a text example before the command. \gab{This'll be added after
the two ``Rascunho'' slides} Here's the text after. There's no way I can move
the command to the end, I have to leave it here, since I have more than ten
thousand blocks like this.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not support multiple occurrences of `\gab` within a call to `\questao`.

Comment: It's actually impossible to express how much you've helped me. Thanks a lot for that!